# How to obtain user acces token or authorization code without redirecting to facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a .Net application that will work in backend and i need to add the functionality to create a post on my facebook page.
 and I also have created facebook APP for this, but i have found all the way to create a post on facebook page after redirecting  to facebook window.
But i don't want to add any such functionality  to redirect i.e i don't want to redirect user to my application to any another window or app.
To solve this i need of your help to know that is there any another way to perform this action means authenticate user without having to expose the 
facebook side .

Please let me know if you have any solution regarding of this and reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript SDK for this.

In order to get a user token without using the javascript SDK, you need to authenticate the user using the OAuth dialog redirect.

**Follow this link for it:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Comment: No, i want the server side flow, But in server side redirection is must. is there any way that i can enter my username and password with  API or something else that i obtain token internally very smoothly. please suggest me.?

Comment: and even by javascript SDK it opens the facebook side popup . can i use my own popup where i can put the username and password for authentication.

Comment: Yes. for fb authentication!!